# AngularJS - Get data by ID

Tags: controller, get, routes, angularjs

I got the following situation:
I got some custom marker an a static (non google) map. I display(and filter) the marker with this code:

```
<div ng-controller="DealerDetailsListCtrl">
    <a ng-click="showdetails=!showdetails" href="#/dealer/{{marker.id}}" class="marker" style="left:{{marker.left}};top:{{marker.top}}" ng-repeat="marker in dealer|zipFilter:zipCodeLookup:countryLookup"></a>
</div>
```

I route it to the "dealer-details.html" where I successfully display the ID:

```
  <div class="alldealermodal" ng-controller="DealerDetailsCtrl">      
    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>
```

with this controller / routing:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/dealer/:id', {templateUrl: 'files/tpl/dealer-details.html', controller: DealerDetailsCtrl}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

and

```
function DealerDetailsCtrl($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
}
```

Since I'm very new to angularJS I would like to know, how could I get all the data by the ID.

My json file looks like this:

```
[
{
    "id": "2",

    "name": "Laden Dortmund",
    "strasse": "Unionstr.",
    "hausnr": 1,
    "plz": "45525",
    "stadt": "Dortmund",
    "land": "DE",
    "url": "http://www.google.de",
    "tel": "0234-234568",
    "email": "lade@indortmund.de",
    "left": "200px",
    "top": "300px",
    "lowRange":60000,
    "highRange":70000
},
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Laden Unna",
    "strasse": "Berlinerstr.",
    "hausnr": 134,
    "plz": "78654",
    "stadt": "Unna",
    "land": "AT",
    "url": "http://www.bing.de",
    "tel": "0234-11223344",
    "email": "lade@inunna.de",
    "left": "250px",
    "top": "500px",
    "lowRange":40000,
    "highRange":50000
}
]
```

and so on.... and I would like to get all data from the chosen id. How can I do that? Would somebody give ma a hint?

I use this controller to get ALL the data from the json:

```
function DealerListCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $scope.dealer = [];
  $http.get('files/js/dealer.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.dealerall = data;
  });
  $scope.orderProp = 'id';
}
```

Comment: Just iterate over the array in a function and return the object with the correct id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to set `ng-controller="DealerDetailsCtrl"` in `dealer-details.html`, because `ng-view` will take care of that.

Secondly, you should provide a [service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services) to retrieve your data:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('dealerService', function($http) {
   return {
      getDealerList function() {
         var dealers = {
            list : []
         };
         // TODO add possible caching via $cacheFactory
         $http.get('files/js/dealer.json').success(function(data) {
            dealers.list = data;
         });
         return dealers;
      },

      // other functions
   };

});
```

In your controllers, where you need to access your dealers, just inject `DealerService`, as you would another service. To fetch a particular entry, just iterate.

Another possibility is use the `resolve` property on [$routeProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24routeProvider) to send the dealer data to the DetailController.

Comment: That doesn't work, am I doing something wrong? Getting the error: ncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function line 5

Comment: Got another problem (sorry, very new to angularjs)... is this correct?
http://pastebin.com/gTHs0vNy - it gives me this error: ReferenceError: dealers is not defined

Comment: You are referencing a function, not executing it.